# Type () does not conform to an undefined protocol

Tags: ios, swift

```
let NumberOfColor: UInt32 = 6

enum BlockColor:Int, CustomStringConvertible{
    case Blue = 0, Orange, Purple, Red, Teal, Yellow
    var spriteName: String{
        switch self {
        case .Blue:
            return "blue"
        case .Orange:
            return "orange"
        case .Purple:
            return "purple"
        case .Red:
            return "red"
        case .Yellow:
            return "yellow"
        }
    }
    static func random() -> BlockColor{
        return BlockColor(rawValue:Int(arc4random_uniform(NumberOfColor)))!
    }
}
```

and mistake is"enum BlockColor:Int, CustomStringConvertible{...}"

> Type 'BlockColor' does not conform to protocol 'CustomStringConvertible'

I try to make the game by swift,but i have a problem with the code
Can anyone tell me why there happen this mistake?
(My English is not good, that is my first question, thank everyone

this question have be done , thanks.
but have same question

```
class Block: Hashable, CustomReflectable{

let color:BlockColor

var column: Int
var row: Int
var sprite: SKSpriteNode?

var spriteName: String{
    return color.spriteName
}

var hashValue: Int{
    return self.column ^ self.row
}

init(column:Int, row:Int, color:BlockColor){
    self.column = column
    self.row = row
    self.color = color
}

var description: String{
    return "\(color): [\(column), \(row)]"
}
```

}
func == (lhs: Block, rhs: Block) -> Bool{
    return lhs.column == rhs.column && lhs.row == rhs.row && lhs.color.rawValue == rhs.color.rawValue
}

Comment: Please post the code, not an image of the code.

Comment: i don't how to post the code, someone can teach me ? :(

Comment: @xiebochen It's easier than posting images : copy and paste (⌘C - ⌘V)

Comment: Paste the code into the question.  It needs to be indented by 4 spaces to recognized as code, and make sure there is a blank line above and below the code.  If you need to add the indentation, drag select the code in the SO editor and press the `{}` button in the tool bar.

Comment: thank a lot, i done my post, but i have no idea for the mistake...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste your code in a playground and read the error message

> Swift.CustomStringConvertible:15:16: note: protocol requires property 'description' with type 'String'

Alternatively <kbd>⌘-click</kbd> on `CustomStringConvertible` to figure out the required methods.

The error message means you have to implement the property `description` in the `enum`

```
var description : String {
   return "\(self.rawValue)"
}
```

PS: you can also simply replace `spriteName` with `description`

Comment: i try to add this description, but Xcode tell add the "default" in the switch, can u tell me why?

Comment: You forgot to add the case `Teal` in the `switch` statement.

Comment: thank a lot!!! it work, but.... have other question, I create class and also use "CustomReflectable" and have implement "description" , but it tell me have same mistake like previously

Comment: `CustomReflectable` is not the same as `CustomStringConvertible` and requires different methods / properties. As mentioned above ⌘-click on `CustomReflectable` to find out.

Comment: @vadian thank u very much, i will use ⌘-click to figure out question, thank!!